# Salesforce Meta quick link missing

Tags: support

Before the new hotness top bar I used to be able to click the StackExchange button which had a dropdown arrow to allow navigating to other communities or the Salesforce meta page.

Now I click it, it takes me to the StackExchange home page where the the dropdown shows but only the community page not the community meta.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there an easier way to get to the meta?

[image: dropdown]

[image: no dropdown]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just on the right now.

[image: Site Switcher]